# Concatenate address lines efficiently

Tags: python, algorithm, concatenation, street-address

My database stores some standard address lines fields (address line 1,2.. City, Country, Postal/zip code) and I would like to concatenate them to a human form. I've written the following code but I'm not sure if this is very efficient with a bunch of if statements. (Written in python but it's the algorithm that I care about)

```
def human_readable_address(self):
    '''
    Return human readable address
    If address1 is empyty, return None
    '''
    addr = ""

    if(self.address1):
        addr += self.address1 + ", "
    else:
        return None

    if(self.address2):
        addr += self.address2 + ", "
    if(self.city):
        addr += self.city + ", "
    if(self.postal_code):
        addr += self.postal_code + ", "
    if(self.country):
        addr += self.country + ", "

    return addr
```

What do you guys think? Is there a better way?

Comment: "Python String join() The join() is a string method which returns a string concatenated with the elements of an iterable." That's what I would use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using string concatenation (which creates a new string each time) you could use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
def human_readable_address(self):
    '''
    Return human readable address
    If address1 is empty, return None
    '''

    if not self.address1:
        return None

    return ', '.join(filter(None, [self.address1, self.address2, self.city,
                                   self.postal_code, self.country]))
```

Comment: The list creation can be compacted in 2 lines. EDIT: Better :)

Comment: Well, it can even be 1 line if desired.

Comment: Hmm, you would loose the "break" if `not self.address1` and would have to do the `filter` every time. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension, joined into a string, to get the address in the format you need:

```
address_1 = "first"
address_2 = False
address_3 = "third"

def make_address(*args):
  return "".join(["%s,\n" % x for x in args if x])[:-2]

address = make_address(address_1, address_2, address_3)

print(address)
```

As in: https://repl.it/repls/LiveJuniorLanservers